# MVC 5. Model reference file missing Model.Context.cs. Looking in users folder

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a Class Library Application that houses my Models. I reference this class in my applications. I recently added the solution to TFS for testing at other locations. I found an immediate problem.

When someone tries to load the project on their computer it throws an error saying It cannot find source "ProjectModel.Context.cs". When I step into the connection to the Entity it says the Original location is my computers Users folder. ("c:\users\asdf\Documents\Visual Studio...."). Obviously they will not have my user account folder on their PC.

Did I build the Class Library that has my models incorrectly? Or is my application reference settings wrong? Why does the reference try to look in my user folder?

The Class Library builds to an Output path on the network (everyone has access to). But I did notice that the .edmx file in this application is pointing to a local directory. Should the .edmx model files be pointing to a network location instead?

Settings for Class Library Model

1. Build Action - Entity Deploy
2. Copy to Output Directory - Do not copy
3. Custom Tool - Entity ModelCodeGenerator
4. Custom Tool Namespace -
5. File Name - APP.edmx
6. Full Path - c:\Users\asdf\APP.edmx

Settings for the Reference to the class library in my project

1. Name - APP
2. Aliases - global
3. Copy Local - True
4. Culture -
5. Description -
6. Embed Interop Types - False
7. File Type - Assembly
8. Identity - APP
9. Path - \network location\APP.dll
10. Resolved - True
11. Runtime Version - v4.0.30319
12. Specific Version - False
13. Strong Name - False
14. Version - 1.0.0.0

Comment: Go to the `Pending Changes` screen in Visual Studio TFS, it's likely that your new Class library has been excluded from checkins. You simply need to include them and then perform another checkin.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `Pending Changes` screen in Visual Studio TFS, it's likely that your new Class library has been excluded from checkins. You simply need to include them and then perform another checkin.